# How do I bake these details?

Tags: baking

In the upper side of the image is the rendered 8K texture. It's how it's supposed to look.
Below is the baked 8K texture, which looks nothing like the original. I baked the displacement map of the original texture into a roughness & normal map and that's how it looks, at 8K.

How do I actually bake these details correctly?

[image]

[image]

Comment: is the top image a real displacement? It's not clear... maybe share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: The original displacement texture was baked into a normal map. I added my node configuration.

Comment: I'm not sure about your Bump plugged into your Roughness but maybe share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I discovered the issue. Since I was using the same UV Map for all objects, I think the normal being baked was from a metal texture and not from the leather one. The solution I'm seeing is to keep the leather part apart from the rest with it's own UV Map.

Comment: mmh perhaps but I'm still not sure your node setup is good...